# Is checking two values by inequality operator faster than checking by subtracting in PHP?

Tags: php, performance

I know this not huge performance impact, I'm asking just out of curiosity.

Logically in computing checking by != should be faster than checking by comparing result of subtraction operation with zero. But I'm not sure either about that and about engine of PHP. To be clear below I've written code examples.

```
if (date('d', $ar[i]) != $current_day)
```

versus

```
if ((intval(date('d', $ar[i])) - intval($current_day)) > 0)
```

Comment: I think your code which you posted, doesn't even work as you want it to. Since `date()` returns a string you would have to get the timestamp from it in order to subtract it

Comment: Ok, I edited the code. Please don't do syntax checking it's not about code, it's about performance.

Comment: You've already written the code - why not run it and find out which is faster that way?

Comment: @Nurlan I think you have to clarify your question and explain a bit more. Especially make an example with some data, so that we see with what data we are working with

Comment: Please don't judge strictly. That's first time I'm asking here question. It may contain wrong code part ant etc. OK let's assume we are comparing two integer values, not date or another type. I'm sorry if I was not clear enough.

Comment: @Nurlan So you are comparing two timestampes? (If yes I would add this to the question)

Answer (score 1):

Well, that depends on what type `$current_day` is, because [PHP's type juggling behavior](http://php.net/language.types.type-juggling) will try to cast when the arity of the operator is of a disparate type. So for example if `$current_day` is an integer, PHP is going to cast the return string of `date` anyway and it ends up becoming an integer comparison. Of course the cast itself may pack on more overhead, but that's pretty much what you're doing with `intval` plus the extra cost of a function call (which is much slower than a cast). If they're both strings the comparison will likely be slower than integer math, but keep in mind you're talking nanoseconds at this point.

## Internal Implementation

If you're really interested in the internal implementation of how PHP will compare two strings, it's basically just C99 `memcmp(3)` underneath the hood.

Here's the [relevant C code in the Zend engine](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_operators.c#2489) if you're interested.

```
ZEND_API int ZEND_FASTCALL zend_binary_strcmp(const char *s1, size_t len1, const char *s2, size_t len2) /* {{{ */
{
    int retval;

    if (s1 == s2) {
        return 0;
    }
    retval = memcmp(s1, s2, MIN(len1, len2));
    if (!retval) {
        return (int)(len1 - len2);
    } else {
        return retval;
    }
}
/* }}} */
```

So it's linear time comparison basically.

## Some final clarification

Since performance interests me a great deal as well I felt it could be beneficial to explain why your hypothesis that a `!=` comparison *should* be faster than subtraction in theory.

At the lowest level of the machine ISA, subtraction requires moving the two integers into registers and moving the result register back to memory for evaluation later. Comparison by `!=` is simpler at the ISA level (again assuming x86 architecture here) since the result register need not be stored and can directly be used in the truth in value operation.

So again, you're talking about basically the difference between an extra hit from CPU to RAM, which your CPU will likely cache in it's data L1 cache anyway, and an extra instruction, which the CPU is also highly likely to cache in its code L1 cache. Though in practice we have so many more layers of high level code at play here that this may or may not be realized in practice.

Of course this only holds true if you're comparing two integers. If you're comparing two strings you have to compare each byte in memory for both strings until you hit a mismatch or the end of the memory block. So that one takes a few more round trips.

Answer (score 0):

Let us imagine you work with timestamps in that case, so its really numbers, not strings, since you cannot substract a string from another.

In you example you has one check on one side (Is A not B?) and two checks on the other side (C is A-B, Is C greater than 0?)

This means no matter, how fast the functions itself are: The one operation will always be faster than the two operations, since all the functions you stated here are nearly the same speed.